# how to bring underlying ladder object behind the table of cells created by 2D array using div tag in javascript my code is

Tags: javascript

i am doing a project the pice of code where i am having problem is as below. The main problem is to set the ladder it comes under the stage specifications or sometimes it goes behind the table created and is not visivle. what i want is to make this gif visible on the cells. please help me out.

Visualizing 2D Array

```
<style>
#stage
{
    width : 300px;
    height : 300px;
    position : relative;

}
.cell
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border : 1px solid black;
    background-color : white;
}
</style>

<div id = "stage"></div>


<div id = "imageDiv" img src="lad1.gif" alt="ladder" width="200" height="300" 


align="middle" style="margin:100px 50px"></div>


<script>

var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");



 //The 2D array that defines the pattern




var pattern = [
[1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 , 0],
[0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 , 1],
[1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 , 0],
[0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 , 1],
[1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 , 0],
[0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 , 1],
[1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 , 0],
[0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 , 1],
[1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 , 0],
[0 , 1 , 0 ,1 , 0 , 1 ,0 , 1 , 0 , 1]];




 //The sixe of each cell


var SIZE = 30;




 //The space between each cell




 var SPACE = 10;




 //Display the array



var ROWS = pattern.length;



 var COLUMNS = pattern[0].length;



 for (var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {



  for (var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++) {


 //Create a div HTML element called cell


  var cell = document.createElement("div");



//Set its CSS class to "cell"


 cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");



//Add the div HTML element to the stage



 stage.appendChild(cell);



 //Make it black if it's a "1"


 if (pattern[row][column] === 1) {



   cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";




  }



 else {


 cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";


 }



//Position the cell in the correct place



 //with 10 pixels of space around it



 cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";


 cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";



   }
}



document.getElementById('imageDiv').style.backgroundImage = '..//lad1.gif';



stage.appendChild(imageDiv);
</script>
```